# How can I add mouseenter() or mouseleave() to multiple elements of the same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a simple game, where you have to traverse from one platform to another, without falling off the edges. Basically, the game starts when you hover over the first platform, and once you get to the final platform, you win. If you hover out at any point, you automatically lose.

I'm working on my first prototype, and I can't seem to combine hover effects for multiple elements using the same class. Whenever I leave the first platform, the event fires despite the overlap with another element of the same class. Is there a way to prevent this?

Here's my code:

```js
$('.platform-win').mouseenter(function() {
  alert("You Win!");
});
$('.platform').mouseleave(function() {
  alert("You Lose!");
});
```

```css
    /*Size & Positioning*/
.platform-container {
  width: 1400px;
  height: 700px;
  position: relative;
}
.platform-win {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  left: 1305px;
  top: 605px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
#one{
  width: 1400px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}
#two{
  width: 100px;
  height: 700px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1300px;
}
/*Animations*/



/*Colors and Fonts*/
.platform-container {
  background-color: grey;
}
.platform-win {
  background-color: green;
}
#one{
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
#two{
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="platform-container">
  <div class="platform-win"></div>
  <div class="platform" id="one"></div>
  <div class="platform" id="two"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure if I got it. Is your problem that mouse leaves fires, because you are leaving an overlaying div on top of the `<div class="platform-win"/>`?

Comment: @linuxrocks if you run the code snippet, you will notice that when you cross from `.platform #one` to `.platform #two`, the mouse leave fires. I don't want that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `relatedTarget`:

```
 $('.platform').mouseleave(function(e) {
        if ($(e.relatedTarget).hasClass('platform-container')) {
            alert("You loose");
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use $(el).each() to iterate through them:

```
$('.platform-win').each(function() {
  $(this).mouseenter(function() {
        alert("You Win!");
    });
    $(this).mouseleave(function() {
        alert("You Lose!");
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried adding it to my code, modifying it for `.platform` specifically, but the problem persists. I think the underlying problem is `this` keyword referring to the current div, so each element is processed individually, not as part of a group. (I am new to js--please correct me if I'm wrong)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like have a global timer variable. Every time your mouse leaves a block, it starts a timer. Every time your mouse enters a block, it stops the timer. If the timer ever gets over 0.01s or whatever value you pick, it counts as a loss. But if user moves from valid box to valid box, the timer shouldn't get that far. Just one idea.